# How to export all projects from Aperture?

Tags: photos, aperture

I would like to export all of the projects from Aperture to a directory in my computer. Since I have many projects (100+), I don't want to export them one by one. Is there a way to batch export them to a directory? For example, my projects might look like this:

- 2011-11-23 Thanksgiving
- 2011-12-24 Christmas
- 2012-07-07 John Wedding

I would like to export them to:

- ~/Pictures/Exports/2011-11-23 Thanksgiving
- ~/Pictures/Exports/2011-12-24 Christmas
- ~/Pictures/Exports/2012-07-07 John Wedding

I appreciate your helps. Thank you.

Comment: What exactly do you want to export? Masters? Versions? Are you migrating away from Aperture? Trying to relocate Masters? The Export dialogue in Aperture has the ability to create a Folder tree as you describe

Comment: I'm sorry for not answering sooner. I am trying to export versions. My plan is to delete the projects after I exported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the material you want to export and File -> Export -> Version.

This will give you the Export dialogue. Look at it closely as it has a lot of options.

Somethings are quite obvious: Where to export to, for instance. But note the others:

Export Preset: This determines the size (length x breadth), file format and compression applied to the image on export. (So, full-size, tiff/jpeg and so on). Note the option at the bottom of the dropdown to Edit - that allows you to create your own Export preset depending you your requirements.

Next note the SubFolder Format. That's what allows you to design a naming scheme for the exported projects. There are presets there, and again, using the Edit option you can devise your own.

I note that you then plan to delete the projects from Aperture. Why? Not sure you've grasped the point and purpose of the app if that's what you're doing...

Comment: I am exporting to JPEG and delete the projects to archive those photos. I am fairly sure that my JPEG will still be viewable (i.e. there will still be viewers for them) five years down the road. Although Aperture is an excellent application I love dearly, I am not sure if it is still around later on. By the way, I have been using Aperture since version 1, so I know that it is a photo manager. I use it to manage current projects (< 1-year-old). For the older projects, I would like to archive to JPEG.

Comment: I would like to add to your answer: 1. Select the projects I want to export, 2. Cmd+A to select all photos within these projects, 3. File->Export->Version. Thank you for helping me out.